# No repositories found

Tags: git, gitolite, cgit

After I installed and configured `cgit`, `gitolite` and `apache`, I got "No repositories found" error when I tried to open page, http://servergit/cgit.

Errors in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[cgi:error] [pid 27680] [client 10.76.6.235:42188] AH01215: Error opening projects file /home/git/projects.list: Permission denied (13)

/etc/cgitrc:
enable-git-config=1   
project-list=/home/git/projects.list
scan-path=/home/git/repositories
```

File and folder permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1  git  git 61      Sep 26 16:54    /home/git/projects.list
drwxr-xr-x. 17 git  git 4096    Sep 28 11:53    git/
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root      41 Sep 6 16:38    home/

groups git
git : git root apache
groups apache
apache : apache root git
groups root
root : root git apache
```

I don't know the cause of `Permission denied (13)` error.

I copied projects.list to `/tmp/projects.list` and changed `cgitrc` to

```
project-list=/tmp/projects.list

ls -l  /tmp/projects.list
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 git  git      61 Sep 28 12:13 projects.list
drwxrwxrwt.  13 root root   4096 Sep 28 14:04 /tmp
```

Then, I got new errors in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[cgi:error] [pid 27681] [client 10.76.6.235:44747] AH01215: Error opening projectsfile /tmp/projects.list: No such file or directory

cat /tmp/projects.list
build-scripts.git
build-scripts-test.git
testing.git
```

I do not understand why it complains `"No such file or directory"`.

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
root     27661     1  0 11:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   27679 27661  0 11:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   27680 27661  0 11:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   27681 27661  0 11:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   27682 27661  0 11:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

This is a `CentOS 7.2` platform.

Can someone please provide some help?

Comment: Markdown, some grammar